# GWT TextArea in ScrollPanel in TabLayoutPanel - how to take 100% of height?

Tags: gwt, layout

Here is a miminal UI demonstrating my problem.  It is the usual UIBinder boilerplate, plus the three widgets: TabLayoutPanel, ScrollPanel, TextArea.  I want the TextArea to take up all the available space of the tab, and I want it to have a scroll bar if it can't fit.  But this code yields a TextArea that is two lines tall. How do you fix this? Why is it ignoring the height?

[image]

In the ui.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
  <ui:style>           
        .scrollPanel {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .textArea {
            height: 100%;
        }
      </ui:style>
  <g:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="20" barUnit='PX'>
     <g:tab>
       <g:header>Text Area</g:header>
       <g:ScrollPanel styleName='{style.scrollPanel}'>
         <g:TextArea ui:field='textArea' styleName='{style.textArea}'></g:TextArea>
       </g:ScrollPanel>
     </g:tab>
  </g:TabLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And in the Java file:

```
package com....client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ResizeComposite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class BugDemoLayout extends ResizeComposite {

    private static BugDemoLayoutUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(BugDemoLayoutUiBinder.class);

    interface BugDemoLayoutUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, BugDemoLayout> {}

    @UiField TextArea textArea;

    public BugDemoLayout() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        StringBuilder junk = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=1; i<300; i++) {
            junk.append("Line " + i + "\n");            
        }
        textArea.setText(junk.toString());
    }
}
```

The module file simply adds the ui to the root:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {       
   BugDemoLayout bd = new BugDemoLayout();
   RootLayoutPanel.get().add(bd);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TabLayoutPanel` and `ScrollPanel` both implement the [RequireResize](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Resize) interface and automatically resize to the available space using absolute positioning.
You specified a relative height (100%) for the content inside the `ScrollPanel`. This doesn't work because the size in the parent isn't explicitly set (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740617/gwt-layoutpanel-size) for more details).

So you can either:

1. Set an explicit size in the ScrollPanel in pixel and then set the Textarea height to 100%.
2. Extend the TextArea and implement the `RequiresResize` interface (implement the onResize() method where you set the height/width of the `TextArea`

The second approach is the cleaner recommend one as it also resizes the `TextArea` when you resize the browser window.
It would look something like that:

TextArea:

```
public class ResizableTextArea extends TextArea implements RequiresResize {

     public void onResize() {

         int height = getParent().getOffsetHeight();
         int width = getParent().getOffsetWidth();
         setSize(width+"px",height+"px");
     }
}
```

You have to put your `TabLayoutPanel` into a `RootLayoutPanel`. This will ensure that there is an unbroken chain of `LayoutPanels` or Widgets that implement `RequiresResize`/`ProvidesResize` interfaces all the way down to your custom TextArea.

Comment: I like this, and it works, almost.  The problem is the inital layout.  At first the UI looks like before, but when I resize the window to trigger onResize(), then the custom TextArea expands as desired.  How to get correct layout in the beginning?  I tried manually calling onResize after adding everything to the RootLayoutPanel - doesn't work.  There is apparently some delay, because if I put that same call in a delayed timer, it will work... but that's all getting ugly.

Comment: Normally the ``RootLayoutPanel`` should take care of calling ``onResize()`` on child widgets which implement the ``RequiresResize`` interface when it is rendered/constructed. This should actually take care of the the initial layout. I am surprised that it doesn't work in your case. How do you construct the TabLayoutPanel? Calling ``onResize()`` manually will not work because the widget is not yet attached to the DOM. (see [here](http://markmail.org/message/waanbhkstg7zpad2) for more details). You can try to call ``foreceLayout()`` on the ``TabLayoutPanel`` which should fix it.

Comment: The code to set up my test app is simple, I'll add to the question in a second. It creates the widget and adds it to the `RootLayoutPanel`.

Comment: `forceLayout()` doesn't work either unless I run it a moment later, with a `Timer`. If I call it immediately after adding the UI to the RootLayoutPanel, `getParent().getOffsetHeight()` returns 0, as mentioned in the link in your comment.

Comment: Your code looks fine and the initial layout should work fine. You can try to remove all CSS attributes and also set a breakpoint in the various onResize() functions (TextArea, TabLayoutPanel) and see if onResize is called and which value getParent().getOFfsetHeight() returns. I have a similar layouts and they work without any additional code.

Answer (score 0):

You're placing a TextArea inside of a ScrollPanel, but the ScrollPanel isn't necessary as the TextArea already has scrollability built-in. If you take out the ScrollPanel, it should work fine (in my testing it works).

Comment: This does not work for me. Maybe it depends on browser and OS. I'm on OS X 10.7, Chrome. The textarea does not scroll, and the only way to to see the later lines is to put the cursor in the textarea and move down with the arrow key.  It looks like the GWT layout panels set overflow:hidden on the textarea.

Comment: Possibly, but my tests worked in both Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7, so it'd be really strange if Chrome on the Mac acted differently in this regard. Perhaps you could minimize your code sample and post it so that we can see where the problem might be?

Comment: I used exactly the minimized code sample in my question, except I commented out 2 lines in the ui.xml file -- the start and end tag of the <g:ScrollPanel>.  So, as you suggested, the TextArea was directly inside the tab.  No scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip the sizing part of this question, but answer the scrolling part (as that never seemed to be resolved?).

I had the same problem, so I placed a `ScrollPanel` inside the tab, and nested an `HTMLPanel` within it, sized to 100% the width and height of that parent `ScrollPanel`.  Then, I used `panel.add( new HTML("my text" ) );` to populate it.

I also replaced `"\n"` with `"<br />"` in my actual long text string. (That was applicable for my needs).

Now, that's not quite the same thing as a `TextArea`, of course, but it does allow you to *display* long running scrolling text inside of a `TabLayoutPanel`.